# Function to count the amount of times two string match in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to find how may times two string matches in c, if we have two or more stars, multiple string combination can be suitable. e.g `"abcdb"` & `"*b*"` matches two times. my current code works but it returns four. I don't what I am missing here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int nmatch(char *s1, char *s2) {
    if (*s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0' && *s2 == '*' && (*s2 + 1) != *s1) {
        return nmatch(s1 + 1, s2) + 1;
    }
    if (*s1 == *s2) {
        return nmatch(s1 + 1, s2 + 1);
    }
    if (*s1 == *s2 && *s1 == '\0' && *s2 == '\0') {
        return 0;
    }
    return (1);
}

int main() {
    char ap[] = "abcd";
    char ab[] = "*b*";
    printf("%d", nmatch(ap, ab));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your first 'if' statement - why are you '+1' the result?

Comment: The third if clause will never be true (second catches that case before).

Comment: To get total number of a match.

Comment: What's missing in general seems to be any kind of "branching": You'd need to count matches for *each* case of `*` matching 0 characters, a single character, two characters ... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your code just does not count the number of different ways `s1` matches pattern `s2`.  It does not even return 1 for identical strings.

The first comparison `(*s2 + 1) != *s1` is incorrect, you probably meant `*(s2 + 1) != *s1` equivalent to `s2[1] != *s1`, but this fix is not enough to correct the algorithm.

Here is a naive implementation that does:

```
int nmatch(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    int count;
    while (*s2 != '\0' && *s2 != '*' && *s1 == *s2) {
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    if (*s2 == '\0')
        return *s1 == '\0';
    if (*s2 != '*')
        return 0;
    while (*s2 == '*')    /* skip all stars */
        s2++;
    if (*s2 == '\0')
        return 1;
    for (count = 0;; s1++) {
        count += nmatch(s1, s2);
        if (*s1 == '\0')
            break;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Well, your code works for this example, but when I compare `abcdb` with `*b**a*`, it returns only 2. It should give 4.

Comment: @chqrlie, well I was talking about the older version. Good you edited. It works +1.

Comment: @chqrlie, well I do not understand, in your original answer, where there was no code, I just made the change you mentioned, and the answer with `abcdb` and `*b**a*`, was 2, but with the code you have posted now it comes 0.  So I was talking about the OP's code with just the change you mentioned.

Comment: @TenTen: can you give an example where it returns 0 erroneously?

Comment: @chqrlie when is use +b+.

Comment: @chqrlie, I know about @ and how is it used to address someone. I was trying to address you. As, making the change you mentioned in your original answer did not work for what I mentioned above.

Comment: @TenTen, do you mean changing `ap[]` or `ab[]`? When I change `ap`, it works and gives 2. When change `ab`, it gives 1 as this program is used for `*`, not `+`. What do you expect when you change `ap` or `ab`.

Comment: + means a star, I'm on my phone I can't use stars.

Comment: @AshishAhuja: OK.  lets remove this discussion.

Comment: @TenTen: `nmatch("abcd", "*b*")` should return 1 and AFAIK does.

Comment: @TenTen, I cannot understand. how `*b*` is not working for you. It works for me. and by the way, how can you compile programs on your phone? I haven't heard about an IDE which runs on a smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

I think your algorithm is just wrong. Together with the flawed implementation this will lead no where.

There's the *input* string and the *pattern* string. If the first character of the pattern is *not* a `*` and is not equal to the first character of the input string, then return 0 (it's a mismatch).

If they're equal, then remove the first character of both the input and the pattern and return the number of matches of the reduced input and pattern.

On the other hand, if the first character of the pattern is a `*`, then (in a loop) sum the number of matches of the remaining pattern with the complete input string, the input string without the first, then without the second character ... and so on until the input string is empty.

If both input and pattern are empty: return 1. If only one of the strings is empty: return 0.

---

I implemented it as direct recursive function (for production use that should be changed into an iterative version):

```
unsigned matches(char const * const input, char const * const pattern) {
  if (! *pattern) {
    // An empty pattern matches only the empty
    // string, nothing else
    return (*input) ? 0 : 1;
  }
  if (*pattern == '*') {
    // a wildcard could be zero to any number
    // of characters. Sum the number of matches
    // for each possibility (excluding the empty
    // rest of input for now)
    char const * rest = input;
    unsigned count = 0;
    while (*rest) {
      count += matches(rest, pattern + 1);
      ++rest;
    }
    // Add matches for the empty rest of input
    count += matches(rest, pattern + 1);
    return count;
  }
  if (! *input) {
    // A non empty, non wildcard pattern cannot
    // match the empty string
    return 0;
  }
  if (*pattern == *input) {
    // non wildcard match, count the ways the rest of
    // the pattern matches the rest of the input.
    return matches(input + 1, pattern + 1);
  }
  else {
    // mismatch!
    return 0;
  }
}
```

([Live with tests](http://ideone.com/fZyG0X))

To deal with the combinatory explosion of possible matches when there are multiple adjacent wildcards in the pattern one could remove these from the pattern first.

Comment: Absolutely!  That's exactly what my proposed correction does.

Comment: @chqrlie Indeed :) One thing to consider is how to handle a case like: input `xxa` and pattern `**a`. Would you count that as one or two matches (I'd say two) ?

Comment: That's a corner case worth specifying. I made the choice to count only `1` to avoid the combinatorial explosion you would get with `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa` and `********************a`, but `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa` and `*x*x*x*x*a` is still pretty large.